# Select based on where condition using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to use select query using linq to list.

in fallowing code `userDtls` is an list & `Common.UserRightVal` is an enum variable

```
userDtls = _userService.GetById(id);
var permission = from udtls in userDtls[0].userRightList 
where udtls.object_name == "Person" && 
(udtls.user_right   == (int)Common.UserRightVal.update
|| udtls.user_right == (int)Common.UserRightVal.add_update_delete_read 
|| udtls.user_right == (int) Common.UserRightVal.allRight)select udtls;
```

Here I want to check permission details for user. My question is if 'where' condition is getting false then also permission variable is showing default records as shown by userDtls list.

Comment: And you question is?

Comment: Can you show us the code of `UserRight`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. userRightList is an list object which contains different data members related to user_right class

Comment: You want only first record of user rights ?

Comment: You need to clarify your question. It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to every one for response. I got answer, here it is.

```
 var permission=(dynamic) null;
 permission = (from udtls in userDtls[0].userRightList
               where udtls.object_name.Contains(objectType) &&
               (udtls.user_right == (int)Common.UserRightVal.readAll
               || udtls.user_right == (int)Common.UserRightVal.read_readAll 
               || udtls.user_right == (int)Common.UserRightVal.add_update_delete_read
               || udtls.user_right == (int)Common.UserRightVal.allRight)
               select udtls).FirstOrDefault();
```